# Flutter and Adafruit Feather nRF52: Could not locate CCCD descriptor

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit, nrf52

I'm trying to set up notify so that my BLE with sensor can send data to my android phone. My embedded code is based off of the example for Custom HRM on Adafruit's site (https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-nrf52-feather-learning-guide/custom-hrm ) and the code for flutter is based off flutter blue's example

```
for (final BluetoothService service in services) {
   if(service.uuid == widget.serviceID){
        for (final BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic in service.characteristics) {
          if(characteristic.uuid == widget.charID) {
            await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
            characteristic.value.listen((value) {
              print(value);
            });
           }
         }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(set_notification_error, could not locate CCCD descriptor for characteristic: 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, null, null)
```

I tested my flutter code for every available characteristic in case my ID is wrong (it's not though). I also tried printing out all descriptors for that characteristic and found out there's none.

In the example adafruit code, we don't need to add any descriptors, we only need to do

```
characteristic.setProperties(CHR_PROPS_NOTIFY); 
characteristic.setPermission(SECMODE_OPEN, SECMODE_NO_ACCESS);
```

Am I missing something? How can I fix this?

Comment: You are missing some knowledge on [Bluetooth GATT](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html). The GATT attribute "Model Number String"(aka UUID "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") has no *Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor* and therefore the error.

Comment: I tried setting the UUID on the adafruit as shown in their example: BLEService hrms = BLEService(UUID16_SVC_HEART_RATE);
BLECharacteristic hrmc = BLECharacteristic(UUID16_CHR_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT); but on flutter I receive the values on the service "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" and the characteristic "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" which is not the correct UUID but the data values are correct

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It was a hardware issue. Service and characteristic UUIDs weren't setting correctly. Tested on a new Feather nRF52 and everything is good.